# AWS Sagemaker won't let me use an assumed role?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a `HyperparameterTuner` job in Sagemaker. We only use assumed roles, so my ARN looks like:

`arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/ROLE_NAME/email@company.com`

However, when I try to create a job according to [AWS's tutorial](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/hyperparameter_tuning/xgboost_direct_marketing/hpo_xgboost_direct_marketing_sagemaker_python_sdk.ipynb), I get the following error:

```py
(not all code included)
>>> tuner = HyperparameterTuner(
    xgb, objective_metric_name, hyperparameter_ranges, max_jobs=20, max_parallel_jobs=3
)
>>> tuner.fit()

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateHyperParameterTuningJob 
operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 
'arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/ROLE_NAME/email@company.com' at 
'trainingJobDefinition.roleArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression 
pattern: ^arn:aws[a-z\-]*:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@\-_/]+$
```

The error message states that the role must have `iam::123:role/`. This is problematic because assumed roles look like `sts::123:assumed-role/`.

Is there some way to format my assumed role into something the `HyperparameterTuner` will accept, or are assumed roles simply not compatible with AWS Sagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the role name to a simple string, do not add numbers or anything of that sort, an example would be "sm-overall-role".